# How does the compiler handle statements that are always true or false?

Tags: .net

Whenever I need to temporarily disable a section of code in a block, I will wrap it in a statement that is always false, e.g.:

```
if (1 == 2)
{
    // disabled code
}
```

and when I need to re-enable it, I set the statement to evaluate to true.

```
if (1 == 1)
{
    // enabled code
}
```

Which obviously always returns false/true respectively.

How does the compiler handle an instance like this where it will obviously always fail/pass? Does it get optimized away or evaluated every single time?

Comment: Why not use `#if ... #endif` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think OP might not know about it. In that case, it'd make a pretty good answer!

Comment: @HenkHolterman Trufuly, I only ever used #if for #if DEBUG. I never actually thought to do any other condition in it. That is pretty helpful.

Comment: @grooveplex Yes, very useful. But my curiosity is still peaked about the compiler.

Comment: just checked in LINQPad, and the condition and disabled code are not included in the IL, with and without optimizations enabled

Comment: btw, it's "piqued".

Comment: Edit > Advanced > Comment Selection is the way the IDE makes this quick and obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a very simple example of your hypothetical code on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) and inspected the [IL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), and lo: the compiler detected that `1 == 2` is always false, and replaced it with... <s>a single instruction: [`nop`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)</s> nothing. Hooray!

Then, I tried another condition, `Math.E == 2`, and that also worked. For good measure, I tried `Math.Pow(3, 2) == 10`, but that didn't get optimized away, probably because it's a method call.

TL;DR: The C# compiler seems to be kinda smart about this, but only with things that can be proven at compile time.

For a more idiomatic approach to your original question, see [Henk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589150).

Comment: Thank you grooveplex. This pretty much nails down the idea of the question. I’ll further research method calls in comparisons. I know that in languages like JavaScript running with chromes V8 the compiler will eventually “assume” the return value based on the input. I wonder if .net is similar

Answer (score 1):

The C# language specification describes [constant expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#constant-expressions), which are expressions that can be evaluated at compile-time. The compiler will calculate constant expressions and act as if the program stated the appropriate values. So if I say `1 + 2` then the compiler will treat that as `3`.

The specification also describes the concept of [statement reachability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#end-points-and-reachability). Essentially, the spec includes rules for how the compiler determines whether statements can ever possibly be reached. The compiler can use constant expressions to determine whether certain paths through the code are impossible to reach.

Your case involves an `if` statement:

```
if(1==2){
    /* disabled code */
}
```

[The rules for the `if` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-if-statement) states:

> The first embedded statement of an `if` statement is reachable if the `if` statement is reachable and the boolean expression does not have the constant value `false`.

(The phrase "first embedded statement" refers to the code or code block following the `if`, in your case the `{ /* disabled code */ }` section. If you had an `else` there would be a "second embedded statement".)

To rephrase the rule, the interior of an `if` statement is unreachable ("dead code") if the condition for the `if` is something the compiler can guarantee is `false`. If the compiler can guarantee it's `true`, or if the compiler cannot make a guarantee one way or the other, then the code is reachable (assuming, of course, that wherever you put the `if` statement is itself reachable).

---

Now I don't believe the spec explicitly says what a compiler should do when it encounters unreachable code, besides requiring the compiler to emit a warning and prohibiting the compiler from emitting an error. In other words, a compiler could choose to generate IL (the code stored in .NET `.dll`s and `.exe`s) for unreachable code, even though it knows that code wouldn't be used in normal execution.

I thought maybe the official C# compiler that ships with Visual Studio might choose to generate IL for unreachable code during debug builds, so you could explicitly jump into the block with a debugger. That does not appear to be the case; the following C#:

```cs
static void CallMe()
{
    if (1 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LOL");
    }
}
```

compiles into the following IL when "optimize code" is off:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  CallMe() cil managed
{
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] bool V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  br.s       IL_0005
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Program::CallMe
```

This IL stores the value `0` (for `false`) into a temporary boolean variable - so at least the IL is "evaluating" the constant value `1 == 2` in some sense - and then there's a branch instruction that causes the code to jump... to the very next line. So it looks like the C# compiler still acts like there's an `if` block, just that (1) that block is empty and (2) the code jumps over that block unconditionally.